# How to upload data (text, images) to Parse.com with Java program?

Tags: java, ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm building an iOS App in Swift on Parse.com and all my data will be calculated by a real-time Java program (using Eclipse). How can I upload these data to the Parse database? Since the tutorial and SDK on Parse.com are for Android, I can't use that to work with my Java code.

Comment: Most of the Android SDK looks to be plain Java.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native Java SDK from Parse but you could use the [REST Api](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide) and [HttpUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class or any other http framwork to connect to the Parse API.